# Changing frame start in smoke domain

Tags: animation, keyframes, smoke-simulation, effects

I wanted to add a quick smoke effect to my animation that starts at some point in the middle of the animation.

When running the default configuration for the smoke, it seems to render fine.

But the moment I have tried to set the Frame Start value in the Physics Properties for the smoke domain, it suddenly becomes all blurry:
[image]

I have tried deleting the cache folder, but it did not seem to work.

When looking frame by frame, the frames inside the range given seem fine, it is the ones out of the scope that look like this instead of no showing smoke at all.

Furthermore, when running the entire animation, then all of the animation sequence looks the same as in the picture.

What is the source of the problem here?